# Empty results when filtering based on position in XQuery

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, flwor

I tried to print the details of 3rd and 4th products in the catalog, but I am  getting empty results.

XML input:

```
<catalog>
  <product dept="WMN">
    <number>557</number>
    <name language="en">Fleece Pullover</name>
    <colorChoices>navy black</colorChoices>
  </product>
  <product dept="ACC">
    <number>563</number>
    <name language="en">Floppy Sun Hat</name>
  </product>
  <product dept="ACC">
    <number>443</number>
    <name language="en">Deluxe Travel Bag</name>
  </product>
  <product dept="MEN">
    <number>784</number>
    <name language="en">Cotton Dress Shirt</name>
    <colorChoices>white gray</colorChoices>
    <desc>Our <i>favorite</i> shirt!</desc>
  </product>
</catalog>
```

what I tried:

```
SELECT xDoc.query('  for $prod in //product
let $x:=$prod
return (<Item>{data($x[3])}{data($x[4])}</Item>)') 
FROM  AdminDocs
where  id=6
```

Output displayed:

```
<Item />
<Item />
<Item />
<Item />
```

Comment: Please read [ask] on what to include in a good question. Especially, "i am getting errors" is not a reasonable problem description _at all_. Please provide _detailed_ information on the error and current output.

Comment: sure sir i made the changes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This defines a loop over all products:

```
for $prod in //product
```

For each of those products, you return the third and fourth node out of a sequence of a *single* product, which obviously will yield empty nodes:

```
let $x:=$prod
return (<Item>{data($x[3])}{data($x[4])}</Item>)
```

For a better understanding, return the whole product node each time:

```
for $prod in //product
return <item>{ $prod }</item>
```

Which will result in something like this:

```
<item>
  <product dept="WMN">
    <number>557</number>
    <name language="en">Fleece Pullover</name>
    <colorChoices>navy black</colorChoices>
  </product>
</item>
<item>
  <product dept="ACC">
    <number>563</number>
    <name language="en">Floppy Sun Hat</name>
  </product>
</item>
<item>
  <product dept="ACC">
    <number>443</number>
    <name language="en">Deluxe Travel Bag</name>
  </product>
</item>
<item>
  <product dept="MEN">
    <number>784</number>
    <name language="en">Cotton Dress Shirt</name>
    <colorChoices>white gray</colorChoices>
    <desc>Our <i>favorite</i> shirt!</desc>
  </product>
</item>
```

And each of those `<product/>` elements being a `$prod[1]`. Try:

```
for $prod in //product
return <item>{ $prod[1] }</item>
```

which will return the exactly same result, compared to

```
for $prod in //product
return <item>{ $prod[2] }</item>
```

(or any other positional predicate) resulting in empty `<item/>` nodes.

Finally, to return only the third and fourth products, shift the positional predicate into the `for` loop argument:

```
for $prod in //product[position() = 3 or position() = 4]
return <item>{ $prod }</item>
```

(and apply `data(...)` as needed, but I'd guess it won't yield the results you expect here).